# When implementing Apple in app purchases can I use Stripe? The app is written in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase

I have a subscription based application that has no free content. Apple rejected it because I do not use in-app purchases to allow the user to sign up. The (current) only way to register is the go to the website and register/pay. Google accepted the app.

I use Stripe for collecting purchases/subscriptions on the web. As far as I can tell I can not use Stripe with apple in-app purchases. It seems though that I can use RevenueCat? Has anyone used Stripe for in-app purchases? The application is written in Flutter/Dart.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m only able to comment on the in-app purchase for Stripe. For subscriptions, Apple’s developer terms [0] require an in-App Purchase [1]. For physical products, you can use Apple Pay which means you can also use Stripe in your app. You could contact Apple directly as they determine this decision when reviewing your application. 

As for RevenueCat, I have not used it so I am leaving it open here for others to chime in. 

[0] https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=web#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-versus-in-app-purchases